# Appending to array in object appends to all instances

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a text based game. I've tried to make this as organized and professional as possible by trying to follow all conventions.

I have a Map class, shown below:

```
import logging
#local imports
import Npc

class Map:
    def __init__(self, name, npcs = []):
        self.name = name
        connections = []
        if all(isinstance(item, Npc) for item in npcs):
            self.npcs = npcs
        else:
            raise Exception("An NPC was not an instance of NPC")


    def addConnection(self, connection):
        if(connection == self):
            return
        self.name = connection.name
        self.connections.append(connection)
```

My Main class creates two instances of these maps named forest, and village.
The point of this code is to add village into the connections array of forest:

```
village = Map("Village")
forest = Map("Forest")
forest.addConnection(village)
```

It seems simple enough. But for some reason, when `forest.addConnection(village)` is run, or even if i do `forest.connections.append(village)`, the Map instance "village" gets added to the connections array of both forest, and village.

According to the debugger, after forest.addConnection(village) is run,
my two objects look as shown:

```
village (Map)
|------> name="village"
|------> connections = [village]

forest (Map)
|------> name="forest"
|------> connections = [village]
```

Why is this happening? Nowhere in my code do I add anything to village's connections array. Is there something about object oriented programming in Python I'm not understanding? Should I make village and forest classes that inherit/extend the Map class?

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: what is use of `if all(isinstance(item, Map) for item in connections):` during object creation ? You are just checking an empty list

Comment: That's old code I forgot to remove. Before I had a connections parameter in the constructor of Map, but decided it would make more sense to add the maps to the connections array using a function.

Comment: Please present with the current code that is creating an issue. This code looks ok. guess you may have passed a class variable reference to `collection` field earlier

Comment: Now your instances don't even have a `self.connections` to append to. Post something that actually runs and actually demonstrates the problem when run.

Answer (score -1):

Try to avoid call a constructor as default argument of a function.
This is the cause of your issue.

Exemple :

```
>>> class Map():
...     def __init__(self, a=list()): # do __init__(self, a=[]) produce same result
...             print(a)
...             a.append("hello")
... 
>>> b = Map()
[]
>>> b = Map()
['hello']
>>> b = Map()
['hello', 'hello']
>>> b = Map()
['hello', 'hello', 'hello']
>>> b = Map()
['hello', 'hello', 'hello', 'hello']
```

So insead of doing :

```
def __init__(self, name, npcs = []):
    self.name = name
    ...
```

do

```
def __init__(self, name, npcs = None):
    if npcs is None:
        npcs = []
    self.name = name
    ...
```

Comment: Yes that's an issue, but he is not appending to the `npc` list in the `addConnection` method.

Answer (score -1):

Found the issue. @iElden got me looking in the right place.
In the constructor, I `set connections = []`, not `self.connections = []`.

Thanks for the responses!